# Sugiero que las etiquetas [innosetup] e [inno-setup] sean sinónimos

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

La etiqueta [innosetup](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/innosetup) tiene tan solo 3 preguntas, mientras que [inno-setup](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inno-setup) tiene 13.  Lamentablemente, no tengo repuetación suficiente en ninguna de las dos para sugerir el sinónimo de otra forma.

(editado por el mod)

Voten abajo porfa!!!!!

Comment: yendoooooo a unirlassss

Comment: baah... cual les gusta mas?

Comment: @gbianchi imagino que la que tiene 13 preguntas (con guión) sea más usual.

Comment: acepta la respuesta asi queda cerrada.. dale?

Comment: Hecho, @gbianchi, ya está aceptada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

dejemos [inno-setup](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inno-setup) como la primaria!!!!!

Comment: Digo que esta, esta es la que tiene más preguntas.

Comment: Además inno-setup tiene información de etiqueta bastante completa y la otra no.

Answer (score 1):

dejemos [innosetup](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/innosetup) como la primaria!!!!